# Add Google Scholar as a Firefox search engine?

Tags: firefox, search-engine, google-scholar

Is there a way to add Google Scholar as a search engine for Firefox? Couldn't find a good Firefox add-on for that.

Answer (score 1):

I have found [this FireFox add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/google-scholar-search-engine/?utm_source=addons.mozilla.org&utm_medium=referral&utm_content=search) to be just what I need, and is what I think what you're looking for. It adds Google Scholar as a search engine to Firefox, allowing you to type `@scholar <your query>` into the url bar and it redirects you to the Google Scholar results page with that query.